# Understanding regex in shell

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I came across single grouping concept in shell script.

```
cat employee.txt

101,John Doe,CEO
```

I was practising SED substitute command and came across with below example.

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\).*/\1/g' employee.txt
```

It was given that above expression matches the string up to the 1st comma.

I am unable to understand how this matches the 1st comma.

Below is my understanding

```
s - substitute command
/ delimiter
\ escape character for (
( opening braces for grouping 
^ beginning of the line - anchor
[^,] - i am confused in this , is it negate of comma or mean something else?
```

why `*` and again `.*` is used to match the string up to 1st comma?

Comment: sed 's/\([^,]*\).*/\1/g' employee.txt

Comment: above is the original command

Answer (score 3):

`^` matches beginning of line outside of a character class `[]`. At the beginning of a character class, it means *negation*.

So, it says: non-comma (`[^,]`) repeated zero or more times (`*`) followed by anything (.*). The matching part of the string is replaced by the part before the comma, so it removes everything from the first comma onward.

Comment: You should probably tweak that to say `Inside a character class, it means negation IF it's the first character listed` and `^` doesn't outside of a character class REALLY matches `beginning of string` rather than `beginning of line`, it's just that sed is line-oriented and so the 2 things tend to be the same (though idk how that works when you have all that hold-space/pattern-buffer/beam-me-up-Scotty nonsense that you hear about when trying to force sed to process multiple input lines simultaneously).

Answer (score 1):

I know 'link only' answers are to be avoided - Choroba has correctly pointed out that this is:

> non-comma ([^,]) repeated zero or more times (*) followed by anything (.*). The matching part of the string is replaced by the part before the comma, so it removes everything from the first comma onward.

However I'd like to add that for this sort of thing, I find [`regulex`](http://jex.im/regulex/) quite a useful tool for visualising what's going on with a regular expression.

The image representation of your regular expression is:

[image: Your regex visualised]

Comment: Thank you. Thanks again for sharing the visual link. Its very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Given the string "foo, bar", `s/\([^,]*\).*/\1/g`, and more specifically `\([^,]\)*)` means, "match any character that is not a comma" (zero or more times). Since "f" is not a comma, it matches "f" and "remembers" it. Because it is "zero or more times", it tries again. The next character is not a comma either (it is o), then, the regex engine adds that o to the group as well. The same thing happens for the 2nd o.

The next character is indeed a comma, but `[^,]` forbids it, as @choroba affirmed. What is in the group now is "foo". Then, the regex uses `.*` **outside** the group which causes zero or more characters to be *matched but not remembered*.

In the replacement part of the regex, `\1` is used to place the contents of the remembered text ("foo"). The rest of the matched text is lost and that is how you remain with only the text up to the first comma.